# How to set the default of a class parameter to another class instance which has its own default parameters in Python

Tags: python, class, parameters, parameter-passing

I am trying to set the default variable of a class to some instance of another class which has its own default parameter. The problem I then face is that de setting of the parameter to the default does not seem to create a new instance.

Here is what I mean:

```
class TestA:
    def __init__(self, x = 2):
        self.x = x
        
class TestB:
    def __init__(self, y = TestA()):
        self.y = y
```

Now when I run

```
>>>> t = TestB()
```

I get what I expected: `t.y.x = 2`. To the best of my understanding, what happened was that `__init__` set `t.y = TestA()`, and since `TestA()` was called without arguments, it set `t.y.x = 2`.
Finally I run `t.y.x = 7`.

In the next step I do this:

```
>>>> s = TestB()

>>>> s.y.x
     7
```

I expected that `s.y.x == 2`.

Evermore so because when I just use `TestA`, then

```
>>>> a = TestA()

>>>> a.x = 7

>>>> b = TestA()

>>>> b.x
     2
```

How come it doesn't work as expected for `t` and `s`?

Also, how can I properly use a construction like this where the default for attribute `y` is an instance of `TestA` with the default for the attribute `x`.

Comment: Because [the default value of a function is computed only once, when the `def` value is encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549768/lifetime-of-default-function-arguments-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

it's occours becouse the way dafault arguments work in Python.

You can use this approach:

```
class TestA:
    def __init__(self, x=2):
        self.x = x

class TestB:
    def __init__(self, y=None):
        if y is None:
            y = TestA()
        self.y = y
```